# Laravel Predefined options in form request

Tags: laravel, laravel-formrequest

I've created a FormRequest to validate some fields, and I would like that one of those fields only accept the options that a I give it

Searching I found something like this

`"rule" => 'required|in:Option1,Option2,Option3',`

This accept only the predifined options, but in the error message only shows

`"The rule type is invalid."`

And I would like that too shows the valid options predefined in the rules.
How could i do this?

Comment: You can override the **messages** method of the **FormRequest** class to customise the error messages. - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#customizing-the-error-messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I modified my rule to this:

```
"rule" => ['required', 'in:Option1,Option2,Option3']
```

and I customized the error message with the following

```
public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'rule.in' => 'The rule field must be Option1, Option2 or Option3.'
        ];
    }
```